# Paperclip has_attached_file not working with Rails establish_connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, multiple-databases

I am trying to access images from paperclip using establish_connection.
Here is my code of model **article.rb**

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

  if Rails.env.production?
    establish_connection SECONDARY_DB_CONFIG
  else
    establish_connection "article_#{Rails.env}"
  end

    has_many :assets, dependent: :destroy

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets
    validates_associated :assets
end
```

file **asset.rb**

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base

  if Rails.env.production?
    establish_connection SECONDARY_DB_CONFIG
  else
    establish_connection "article_#{Rails.env}"
  end

  belongs_to :article, polymorphic: true
    has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :large=> "1200x700",:medium => "800x" }

  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/png", "image/jpeg"]
end
```

And Code in view

```
<% Article.all.each do |article| %>
    <div class="project-item col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <% if article.assets.length > 0 %>
            <img src="<%= article.assets.last.image.url(:medium) %>" alt="<%=article.name%>" />
        <% end %>
        <div class="hover-title">
            <h2 class="project-title"><%= article.name%></h2>
            <p><%= property.short_desc %></p>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

it throws error like this

> undefined method `has_attached_file' for Asset (call 'Asset.connection' to establish a connection):Class

Comment: I fail to see why undefined method has anything to do with establishing a database connection. The issue will be that the gem isn't being loaded for some reason - are you sure you added the paperclip gem to your Gemfile? did you run bundle install? Post your Gemfile to the question. Why are you even establishing a database connection for every model anyway?

Comment: @henners66 I need to use some other project database in current project, thats why.
And for gem that I've been using the updated paperclip gem

Comment: ok fair enough, however I still think that's a red herring - the issue is more likely that the gem isn't being loaded for whatever reason, that should be ruled out first. I will infer from your previous comment that you have added the gem to the Gemfile and run `bundle install` - did you also restart the server?

Comment: I've been doing this 3-4 times since I faced this issue. Kindly provide me a better solution for this

Comment: I'm only trying to help rule out the obvious ... I can't infer from your question what you have or haven't tried yet. My apologies and good luck with resolving your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install paperclip gem in the existing project, copy and configure AWS S3 information from the project which you need to access.

In Gemfile

```
# paperclip gem for image manipulation
gem 'paperclip', :git=> 'https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip', :ref => '523bd46c768226893f23889079a7aa9c73b57d68'

# aws sdk for uploading at AWS
gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0'
gem 's3'
```

In production.rb

```
# configuration for amazon s3
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_region=> ENV['AWS_REGION'],
    :s3_credentials => {
      :bucket => ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
      :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
    }
  }
```